# How to assign a keyboard shortcut to lookup in dictionary in the books app?

Tags: keyboard, mac, shortcut, dictionary, look-up

I already assigned a keyboard shortcut for Look Up in Dictionary:

[image]

However this shortcut only works if I use it on apps like the Safari. It does not work if I try to use it on the Books app. Why is that so?

I need a keyboard shortcut so that I can quickly look up words when reading in the Books app.

Comment: I don't use book.app myself but if you click on App Shortcuts (shown on your screen cap) you should be able to add shortcuts specifically for any app including books.app.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks. What is the name of the menu command for look up in dictionary?

Comment: That I can't answer as I don't use books.app or the built-in dictionary